# How to get latitude and longitude without using internet?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

Can we get device's current latitude and longitude with out using internet?
I am using following codes..
I am triggering the location listener after the button click.

```
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 20, locationListener);


  private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
  {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
    {
        longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());  
        latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
                  ...
    }
}
```

It fetches longitude and latitude values fine when its connected to internet but returns null when not connected to internet.

What could be the problem? Does LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 20, locationListener need internet to get lat and long?

If internet is required then what's the difference between network provider NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER ?

Answer (score 1):

The network provider translates Cell ID/WiFi readings information to a lat/long address and it needs a data connection to do so. (It accesses Google's servers which has a database of such information)

Use the GPS Provider. It does not need internet.